# (ComputerCraft) (minecraft version 1.7.10) (question) Make a language file reader

Tags: lua, computercraft

I'd like to make a language reader for my operating system, but I cant find anything that helps me.
I want to put the list into my other script. 
Heres the de-de language file (location: /os/bin/):

```lua
    de = {
    Menu = "Menü",
    Shutdown = "Ausschalten",
    MenuLength = 4,
    ShutdownLength = 11
    }
```

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Can you elaborate? You want this list to be put into your other script IF the language `de` is selected?

Comment: Yes, I want to do that, but i want it in different scripts so you can add custom ones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `gsub()` string function/method can do that with your translation table.
You only have to use your language table for that.
Example...

```
# /usr/bin/lua
Lua 5.3.5  Copyright (C) 1994-2018 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> de = {
>>     Menu = "Menü",
>>     Shutdown = "Ausschalten",
>>     MenuLength = 4,
>>     ShutdownLength = 11
>>     }
> language = de
> print(('Menu Shutdown'):gsub('(%g+)', language))
Menü Ausschalten    2
```

If you have to use Lua 5.1 then use `%w`...

```
# /bin/lua
Lua 5.1.5  Copyright (C) 1994-2012 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> de = {
>>     Menu = "Menü",
>>     Shutdown = "Ausschalten",
>>     MenuLength = 4,
>>     ShutdownLength = 11
>>     }
> language = de
> print(('Menu Shutdown'):gsub('(%w+)', language))
Menü Ausschalten    2
```

The length can be measured with the `len()` function/method...

```
> print(('Shutdown'):gsub('(%w+)', language):len())
11
> print(('Menu'):gsub('(%w+)', language):len())
5
```

As you can see in Lua the Umlaut `ü` is measured different.

To include your de-de.lua i suggest `dofile()` that loads it with your specific path...

```
Lua 5.1.5  Copyright (C) 1994-2012 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> dofile('/os/bin/de-de.lua') -- But read comment about security
> print(de['Menu'])
Menü
```

Try to convert the special words with german Umlaut into its byte representation.
And put the bytes into your translation table...

```
$ lua
Lua 5.4.3  Copyright (C) 1994-2021 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> print(('Menü'):byte(1,-1))
77  101 110 195 188
> print('\77\101\110\195\188')
Menü
> de = {Menu = '\77\101\110\195\188'}
> print(('Menu'):gsub('%g+', de))
Menü    1
```

...or for Lua 5.1...

```
$ /bin/lua
Lua 5.1.5  Copyright (C) 1994-2012 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> print(('Menü'):byte(1, -1))
77  101 110 195 188
> print('\77\101\110\195\188')
Menü
> de = {Menu = '\77\101\110\195\188'}
> print(('Menu'):gsub('%w+', de))
Menü    1
```

You also can mix it.
And here are the bytes for: üäößÜÄÖ

```
> print(('üäößÜÄÖ'):byte(1, -1))
195 188 195 164 195 182 195 159 195 156 195 132 195 150
> de = {Menu = 'Men\195\188', Umlaute = '\195\188\195\164\195\182\195\159\195\156\195\132\195\150'}
> print(('Menu Umlaute'):gsub('%w+', de))
Menü üäößÜÄÖ    2
```

Comment: I got an error:
".temp:1: bios:14: [string "de-de"]:1: unexpected symbol"
and also when i try to edit de-de file i get this error:
"de = {
        Menu = window:94: Arguments must be the same length"
I tried the print(de['Menu']) test

Comment: For coding I use Visual Studio Code if that helps

Comment: Whats the name of your de file? - ```de-de``` or ```de-de.lua```?

Comment: the name is de-de

Comment: i also removed the .lua

Comment: Its very late for me right now BUT I think I just found the problem (I can't try it now because tomorrow is school): I think "ü" is an unicode for ComputerCraft and ComputerCraft doesn't accept unicodes

Comment: You can try the byte representation. Look in my post how to produce byte representation.

Comment: It was the Ü and thanks for helping!

Comment: When I recommended `dofile` in another question, I got a few dislikes for "security reasons" :) Alternatively, you can use the Lua deserializer here, which does the same in a more secure way: http://www.computercraft.info/wiki/Textutils.unserialize

Comment: Ahh, thanks ima try that too